# TypeError: unbound method when trying to mock a classmethod

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, class-method

This scripts fails:

```
import mock

class MyClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls):
        print('my_method')

def mocked_method(cls):
    print('I want this method to get called')

with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_method', mocked_method):
    MyClass.my_method()
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/tmp/test_mocking_classmethod.py", line 14, in <module>
    MyClass.my_method()
TypeError: unbound method mocked_method() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and Python binds these to the instance they are looked up on, or in the case of `classmethod`, to the class. Because you didn't use the `classmethod` decorator on the replacement function, it is being bound wrongly (as a regular method instead, so no `cls` is being passed in).

Simply wrap the target in a `classmethod` decorator manually:

```
with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_method', classmethod(mocked_method)):
    MyClass.my_method()
```

Here I applied the `@classmethod` decorator manually, but you could also just use it as intended, as a decorator, directly on the target function:

```
@classmethod
def mocked_method(cls):
    print('I want this method to get called')

with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_method', mocked_method):
    MyClass.my_method()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import mock
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def my_method(cls):
...         print('my_method')
... 
>>> def mocked_method(cls):
...     print('I want this method to get called')
... 
>>> with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_method', classmethod(mocked_method)):
...     MyClass.my_method()
... 
I want this method to get called
```

Comment: This and some additional documentation regarding mocking unbound methods https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods helped me a bit